# Why am I losing a channel when saving an image and how to avoid it?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image which was originally generated as

```
   cv_image = np.zeros((h,w,4),dtype=np.uint8)
```

so clearly when I do this

```
print(cv_image.shape)
```

I get

```
(960,1920,4)
```

(as you can see this image has *4 channels*)

After this I do

```
cv2.imwrite(file_path, cv_image)
```

and I got an image file (stored in the "file path")

Now, *I don't know how to check the number of channels* of an image in linux -if anyone knows please let me know- but then I wrote another script

```
img= cv2.imread(the_file_path)
print(img.shape)
```

and I get

```
(960,1920,3)
```

so I lost one channel! Where did my other channel go, and how can I keep the four channel image??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
im=cv2.imread(the_file_path,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print(img.shape)
```